# master user of AWS RDS does not have privileges to import data, nor to grant the required privileges

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, import, mysql-workbench, database-permissions

I have made a new AWS RDS MySQL instance and I want to import some existing `.sql` data generated from an existing database using MySQL Workbench's export tool.

I connected to the database using the "admin" master user, then started the import.

However, I'm getting this error:
`ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 20: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation`

I tried granting `SUPER` to the master user, and also tried creating a new user with `SUPER`, but got this error:
`Error changing account admin@%%: Missing GRANT OPTION privilege`, even though the master user "admin" does have the `GRANT OPTION` privilege.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gyanendra giri was partially right, but his answer didn't help with MySQL Workbench. Here's how I solved it eventually:

Select `Export to Self-Contained File`, and make sure that `Create Dump in a Single Transaction` is not selected.

Then, click on `Advanced Options...`:

[image]

Set `set-gtid-purged` to "OFF":

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You may have a definer line for a user which doesn't exist for current RDS database. You have something like `` /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ ``
at line 20. You may have to remove that part.

**To remove:**

`` sed -i -e 's/DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`//g' db_dump_name.sql ``

Or replace that user to an existing user. In your case may be `admin`

**To find and replace:**

`` sed -i -e 's/DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`/DEFINER=`admin`@`%`/g' db_dump_name.sql ``

[reference](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/definer-error-mysqldump)

Comment: your answer is for the command line utility mysqldump, I am asking about the desktop app MySQL Workbench...

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have understood it wrong. I've checked my .sql dump files, and they do not have a `DEFINER` in any of the files anywhere...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).